# set windows initial width and height in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, window, bounds

I am working on a Flex mobile application and I want to set initial windows width and height in as3. When my app runs on Desktop, I want to detect screen resolution and set it to windows bounds, something like that
this.width = Capabilities.screenresolutionX
this.height = Capabilities.screenresolutionY

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width and height properties of a NativeWindow to Capabilities.screenResolutionX and Capabilities.screenResolutionY

```
public function AppWindow()
{   
    var options:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
    options.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.STANDARD;
    options.type = NativeWindowType.NORMAL;
    super(options);
    width = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
    height = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
    // to make sure content doesn't scale and aligns to top left set stage properties
    stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hawks, but still problem is there. When I set width and height inside a function, it sets stage width and height not for window. That means my app window is still small but content of tha app seems like stretched up.

Comment: That's a more general scaling issue in actionscript, I have amended my answer to demonstrate how to solve the problem. Also make sure you are extending Native Window. If you are extending a Sprite for your main class then you can access the parent nativeWindow via this.stage.nativeWindow